# C++ Program to find Minimum and Maximum value using One Variable

Tags: c++, max, minimum

Hello Programmers Please Have a Look at this Code and tell me where is problem why i am not able to get Min Index i have to do this with out array where is logical mistake please someone trace.
Thanks Advance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    int minimum = 0;
    int maximum = 0;
    int minimumIndex = 0;
    int maximumIndex = 0;

    cout<<"please enter Loop Limit\n";
    cin>>loop;
    total = loop;

    while (loop > 0)
    {

        cout<<"please enter value "<< counter<<" ";
        cin>>number;

        if(minimum == 0)
        {
            minimum=number;
        }
        else if (number<minimum)
        {
            minimum=number;
            minimumIndex = counter;
        }


        else if(number > maximum)
        {
            maximum = number;
            maximumIndex= counter;
        }
        sum = sum + number;
        counter++;
        loop--;
    }

    cout<<"Sum of Entered Values = " << sum<<endl;
    average=sum/total;
    cout<<"Average Values = "<< average<<endl;
    cout<<"Minimum Value = "<<minimum<<endl;
    cout<<"Minimum Value Enter At Index "<<minimumIndex<<endl;
    cout<<"Maximum Value = "<<maximum<<endl;
    cout<<"Maximum Value Enter At Index "<<maximumIndex<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger?

Comment: no not familiar with proper use of debugger just know it is used to find logical error

Comment: @HassanGillani So, why aren't you getting familiar with it? You could get issues, such as these resolved, much quicker, than writing questions + waiting for someone to respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

This would help :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    int minimum = INT_MAX; //initially set to Maximum value to find minimum
    int maximum = INT_MIN; //Similarily
    int minimumIndex = 0;
    int maximumIndex = 0;

    cout<<"please enter Loop Limit\n";
    cin>>loop;
    total = loop;

    while (loop > 0)
    {
        cout<<"please enter value "<< counter<<" ";
        cin>>number;
        //check for minimum
        if (number<minimum) {
            minimum=number;
            minimumIndex = counter;
        }
        //exclusive check for maximum
        if(number > maximum) {
            maximum = number;
            maximumIndex= counter;
        }
        sum = sum + number;
        counter++;
        loop--;
    }

    cout<<"Sum of Entered Values = " << sum<<endl;
    average=sum/total;
    cout<<"Average Values = "<< average<<endl;
    cout<<"Minimum Value = "<<minimum<<endl;
    cout<<"Minimum Value Enter At Index "<<minimumIndex<<endl;
    cout<<"Maximum Value = "<<maximum<<endl;
    cout<<"Maximum Value Enter At Index "<<maximumIndex<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation as to how your solution helps.

Comment: You may want to note the differences between your posted code and the OP's code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews comments added to the code for diff

Comment: The `while(loop > 0)` loop seems a little unorthodox to me. Would be better to use `while(cin >> number)`

Comment: well it might not be optimised, but it does work..you can give it a try on your preferred IDE. @erip